# How to reatart depend service if the main aervice failed and recovered in topshelf

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, c#-7.0, topshelf

I am having windows service which created using topshelf.  Sometime this service get stopped. So i want it be automatically restarted. So we are   having a onrecovery option in topshelf. Now my problem is when this service recover from failure i should be able to restart another service because my this service got failed. How will i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should have the service have a dependency on that other service to make sure it is running.

On start, the service should send a command to that service to restart its logic.

For a `Topshelf` service to receive commands, the service class should implement `ServiceCustomCommand` or set it up like this:

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.Service<MyService>(sc =>
    {
        sc.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService());

        …

        // Handle custom commands
        sc.WhenCustomCommandReceived((service, control, command) =>
            service.CustomCommand(control, command));
    });
});
```

To send a command to a service, you can use the [`ServiceController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller).[`ExecuteCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.executecommand):

```
using (var thatService = new ServiceController("ThatService"))
{
    thatService.ExecuteCommand(0);
}
```

If you can't had a command to that service, you can also use the `ServiceController` to [`Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop) and [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.start) the service:

```
using (var thatService = new ServiceController("ThatService"))
{
    thatService.Stop();
    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() =>
        {
            thatService.Refresh();
            return thatService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped;
        });
    thatService.Start();
    SpinWait.SpinUntil(() =>
        {
            thatService.Refresh();
            return thatService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
        });
}
```

Or your recovery must be a command where you restart that service and starts this service.